# How to fix an element to the right of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button which i want to fix it's position to the right of a div, the button is toggling the visibility of it's left div, problem is the button loses it's position once the resolution is changing...

Here is an [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/vc9wd9ja/1/)

And here is what I've done so far:

```js
  $('.results_toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('left_hide');
    $('.left').toggle();
  });
```

```css
    .cont {
      width: 100vw;
    }

    .left {
      position: relative;
      width: 50vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: grey;
      float: left;
      border-left: 2px solid white;
    }

    .right {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 50vw;
      float: left;
    }

    .results_toggle:before {
      content: "\f054";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: inherit;
      color: black;
      font-size: 24px;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
      position: absolute;
      top: 14px;
      left: 5px;
    }

    .results_toggle {
      background-color: grey;
      height: 60px;
      width: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 106;
      top: 45vh;
      right: 223px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
      border-top-right-radius: 110px;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }

    .left_hide {
      left: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <div class="cont">
        <div class="left">
        </div>
        <div class="results_toggle">
        <!-- the button -->
        </div>
        <div class="right">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this would be to put the toggle *within* the `.right` div, and position it at `left: 0` so that it is always adjacent to the `.left` div, something like this:

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="results_toggle"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.right {
  position: relative; /* add this */
}

.results_toggle {
  /* remove 'right' */
  left: 0; /* add this */
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vc9wd9ja/3/)

The advantage of this method is that it will be completely unaffected by any change in screen resolution.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what i was looking for - good solution - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that's what you meant, but i simply changed the `left`attribute of the button to `50vw`, the same as your grey box.
[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc9wd9ja/2/)

edit: 
another option: `position: relative` and `float: left` without `left` or `right` property
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc9wd9ja/4/)

Comment: Thanks - i'm looking to find a way to make the button float naturally to it's left div... i don't want to be dependent on the view port position

Comment: Thanks for your time, Rory McCrossan solution is what i went for - appreciate your good will !

Answer (score 1):

You use viewport units , so the values of them will change when changing the viewport size ( resolution ) .

If you want the `arrow` to stay in the middle ( and so, on the right side of the grey div )  , you should center it this way

See snippet below

```js
$('.results_toggle').on('click', function() {

  $(this).toggleClass('left_hide');
  $('.left').toggle();

});
```

```css
.cont {
  width: 100vw;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  float: left;
  border-left:2px solid white;
}

.right {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50vw;
  float: left;
}

.results_toggle:before {
      content: "\f054";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 5px;
}

.results_toggle {
      background-color: grey;
    height: 60px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 106;
    top: 50%;
    right:50%;
    transform:translate(100%,-50%);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
    border-top-right-radius: 110px;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

.left_hide{
  left:0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="results_toggle">

  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the best approach to align elements is to use Flexbox attributes. With those attributes, you can place element as boxes in a row, column...In your case you have a main box .cont with a left side and a right side. This is the result with a Flexbox placement :

[image]

The main div is represented by the red background. Inside you have your left div and aligned with your right button.

Here is the code to make this :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <style type="text/css">
  .cont
  {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: red;
   color: white;
  }
  .left
  {
   background-color: blue;
   margin: 5px;
  }
  button
  {
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="cont">
    <div class="left">
     <p>Left div</p>
    </div>
    <div class="results_toggle">
      <button>Right button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've fixed each property.

You can fix an element at the right of his parent using `absolute` and `relative` `position`. And add the `width` of you child.

Example

```css
.parent{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:#ccc;
position:relative;
}

.child{
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:100px;
transform:translateX(100%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<button class="child">btn</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but ,in my case - the button is a child of the wrap div - i want it to act like it is a child of it's left div